# How to create a system image on ubuntu 16.04 LTS with current applications installed?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, backup

I have installed many applications in my Ubuntu OS like katoolin, Packet-tracer, netbeans, 4k video down-loader etc.

My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS crashes often and I have to reinstall it every time it crashes. The crash is accompanied by this message **Your Graphic hardware had stopped working** followed by four options to troubleshoot it.

It would be easier for me if I could create a system image with the additional software I manually installed so that the next time a crash occurs I could just insert my ISO system image and reinstall it without any extra work.

Comment: [`apt-mark showmanual`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt-mark.8.html): Print the list of manually installed packages

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

> Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program similar to True Image® or Norton Ghost®. It helps you to do system deployment, bare metal backup and recovery.
>
> Two types of Clonezilla are available, Clonezilla live and Clonezilla
>   SE (server edition). Clonezilla live is suitable for single machine
>   backup and restore. While Clonezilla SE is for massive deployment, it
>   can clone many (40 plus!) computers simultaneously.
>
> Clonezilla saves and restores only used blocks in the hard disk. This
>   increases the clone efficiency. With some high-end hardware in a
>   42-node cluster, a multicast restoring at rate 8 GB/min was reported.

<sub>[Copied from CloneZilla main page](http://clonezilla.org)</sub>

In order to install CloneZilla, you will have to enable **Universe** repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then, install CloneZilla:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install clonezilla
```

Tutorial for CloneZilla can be found [here](https://www.geekyprojects.com/cloning/how-to-use-clonezilla-tutorial/)

Comment: Clonezilla is a good tool, but I would recommend to **download an iso file with the current stable version of Clonezilla, and create a CD/DVD/USB boot drive**. Boot from the Clonezilla drive, when you intend to create the image. (Do not boot from the same drive you intend to backup.) It is easiest (both backup and restore), if you make an **image of the whole drive** (not partitions).